# Python>Finding key based on values within a list, from a dictionary

Tags: python

i am using a dict like below and i want a function preferably which returns the key value, based on the value user provides.

```
test_dict={'Name':[abc,def],'Address':['Local','NonLocal']}
```

Used the below function:

```
def find_key_for(input_dict,value):
    result=[]
    for k,v in input_dict.items():
        if value in v:
           result.append(k)
        return result
```

when i use the above function as below:

`print(find_key_for(test-dict,'abc'))` it returns `[]`
while i expected Name

alternatively when i do `(find_key_for(test-dict,'Local'))` it returns `[Address]` which is expected.

why does it not work for Name? what changes can i  make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to un-indent the `return` statement:

```
def find_key_for(input_dict, value):
    result = []
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if value in v:
           result.append(k)
    return result
```

The reason is because if you don't, and have it inside the `for` loop, your function will return after only looping once.

Finally, you can use a nested list comprehension in just one line:

```
test_dict = {'Name': ['abc', 'def'], 'Address': ['Local', 'NonLocal']}

def find_key_for(input_dict, value):
    return [k for k in input_dict if value in input_dict[k]]

print(find_key_for(test_dict, 'abc'))
```

Or a `lambda` function:

```
test_dict = {'Name': ['abc', 'def'], 'Address': ['Local', 'NonLocal']}

find_key_for = lambda input_dict, value: [k for k in input_dict if value in input_dict[k]]

print(find_key_for(test_dict, 'abc'))
```

Output:

```
['Name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please be sure to format your code properly so it's more legible.  You can do this by clicking the code {} up at the top of the screen.

Also, this code works completely fine for me.  One thing that I noticed that could be an issue (but could also be you mistyping it here) was that in the list for 'Name', you have 'abc' and 'def' written without the parantheses, and you could accidentally be assigning it to an object rather than a string.  Also, you wrote "test_dict" as "test-dict" later on.

Comment: apols for the format, yes that was a typo when i was keying it here, but thanks issue resolved with correct indent of return result.

Comment: @ManikSingal glad to hear it! You should mark their response as the answer if you haven't already.